# yfinance AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'tz_localize'

Tags: python

I am just trying to import stock data from yfinance to a dataframe. Using python 3.10

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = yf.download("NFLX",start = "2018-01-01", end = "2022-01-21",interval = "1d")
```

I am getting the following error:
df.index = df.index.tz_localize("UTC").tz_convert(
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'tz_localize'

Is this an issue with the package? Can anyone please help me understand how to fix this?

Comment: Your code works fine on my machine. Is there some other code that could produce this error?

Comment: @JANO, no, that was everything. But that is good to know..... thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same exception using yfinance version 0.1.68. After upgrading to the most recent version (0.1.70) the issue was resolved. In a safe copy of your venv or similar try this on the command line:

```
pip install --upgrade yfinance
```